# Checking if the list of string starts with tuple returning None in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to check if list within a pandas dataframe starts with string from separate list of string. However, I keep getting None.  Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['111,222,2333,444', '211,44', '222,333,444','666,777','555']})
frame['place_holder']=frame['a'].apply(lambda x:((x.upper()).split(',')))
codes = ['55', '33']

def value_check(x,codes):

    if any(str(item).startswith(tuple(codes)) for item in x):
        return True

frame.apply(lambda x: value_check(frame['place_holder'],codes),axis=1)
```

I get None in all rows
I should get True in 3rd row and 5th row.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `apply` wrong: your `lambda` does not use `x` at all. Try:

```
frame['place_holder'].apply(value_check, codes=codes)
```

On another note, you can forget the place holder and chain all the commands:

```
(frame['a'].str.upper().str.split(',').explode()
  .str.startswith(tuple(codes))
  .groupby(level=0).any()
)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: It says series object has no attribute explode. Also first function still returns None in all rows

Comment: `explode` is [available from v0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Btw, your function works fine with just `frame['place_holder'].apply(value_check, codes=codes)`.